# Inter-Sub ErrorLine

Tags: excel, error-handling, vba

I'm looking for a fancy solution on the identification of the line on error in a called `Sub`.

Here is an example which doesn't tell me the line on error in the called `Sub` but only the line in the main `Sub`.

```
Private Sub TestThis()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
a1:
    Call SubError
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    Debug.Print "Error: " & Erl & ", " & Err & ", " & Error(Err)
End Sub

Private Sub SubError()
b1:
    Err.Raise Number:=2000, Description:="MyError"
End Sub
```

The solution I came up with is having a global variable called `error_line` and simply changing it appropriately through the code.

Do you know any fancier solution for this?

Comment: Put an error handler in `SubError`? I don't if I'd call it "fancier", but it would handle it at the level you seem to care about.

Comment: Triggering an error handler on every level would be a more thorough solution for sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VBA, the best practice IMHO is to put an error handler into absolutely **every** procedure you write.  And in every error handler, you could then call another central routine which is handling the error (like writing to a log or something).

Oh well, and the really best practice is to minimize the use of VBA at all ;) - I mean for real: Treat VBA like a scripting language for small projects; but for really big projects, better use C# or VB.NET, and create an add-in or executeable of its own.